# Loading Excel Dashboard in python unsuccessfully

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsx, dashboard

The Tab 'data' has tabular data which is loading correctly using read_excel.
However, 'graph1' tab is a line chart, but it's loading up empty.

How do i make sure the charts in excel are loaded correctly as an image?

[Excel Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRYmO.png)
[Code, Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hytt.png)